# TableView mix up the cells

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I have a TableView with Static Cells with a header which has 4 Cells, one cell in the middle  carries a UIWebView and as footer a section with comments. Each comment has it's own cell. 
My Problem is if the Footer has 4 or more comments, the 4th cell in the footer carries the same UIWebView as the cell in the middle.

My cellForRowAtIndexPath looks like this:

```
// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // Get cell
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellA";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }

    UITableViewCell *contentCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (contentCell == nil) {
        contentCell = [[CustomDetailTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }



    // Display
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
    if (item) {

        // Item Info
        NSString *itemTitle = item.title ? [item.title stringByConvertingHTMLToPlainText] : @"[No Title]";

        // Display
        switch (indexPath.section) {

            case SectionHeader: {

                // Header
                switch (indexPath.row) {

                    case SectionHeaderTitle:
                        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15];
                        cell.textLabel.text = itemTitle;
                        cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0; // Multiline
                        break;
                    case SectionHeaderDate:
                        cell.textLabel.text = dateString ? dateString : @"[Kein Datum]";
                        cell.imageView.image = nil;
                        break;
                    case SectionHeaderSharerFacebook:
                        cell.textLabel.text = @"Share on Facebook";
                        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"f_logo.png"];
                        break;
                    case SectionHeaderSharerTwitter:
                        cell.textLabel.text = @"Share on Twitter";
                        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"twitter-bird-blue-on-white.png"];
                }
                break;

            }
            case SectionDetail: {


                //add webView to your cell
                if (webViewDidFinishLoad == TRUE && indexPath.section != SectionComments) {
                    CGFloat contentHeight = webView.scrollView.contentSize.height;
                    webView.frame = CGRectMake(23, 10, 275, contentHeight);
                } else {
                    webView.frame = CGRectMake(23, 10, 275, 10);
                }
                cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
                [cell addSubview:webView];

                break;
            }
            case SectionComments: {

                NSString *writerText = [[[self.commentParser.commentsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] name] stringByAppendingString:@" schrieb:\n"];
                writerText = [writerText stringByAppendingString:[[self.commentParser.commentsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] description]];
                writerText = [writerText stringByAppendingFormat:@"\n"];
                cell.textLabel.text = writerText;
                cell.imageView.image = nil;
                cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
                cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0; //multiline


                if (cell.textLabel.text == nil) {
                    cell.textLabel.text = @"Keine Kommentare vorhanden";
                    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana-Italic" size:12];
                }
                break;
            }

        }
    return cell;
    }
}
```

Why is the UIWebView in the 4th cell again, and how can I change that ?

Thanks for every answer!

Comment: Where/how are you defining the variables in your `case` statements (like `SectionHeader`)?  Are you maybe accidentally confusing your definitions of `SectionComments` and `SectionDetail`?

Comment: They are typedef's

`typedef enum { SectionHeader, SectionDetail, SectionComments } Sections;
typedef enum { SectionHeaderTitle, SectionHeaderDate, SectionHeaderSharerFacebook, SectionHeaderSharerTwitter } HeaderRows;
typedef enum { SectionDetailImage, SectionDetailSummary } DetailRows;`

Answer (score -1):

The reason is `UITableView` reuses it's cells to conserve memory. There are tons of questions on this topic, I would recommend that you read some ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2269718/440060), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4620095/uitableview-and-cell-reuse), ...). Briefly, when you do:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

for a cell in footer section, you get a cell which was previously in the middle section that contains a `UIWebView`. You need to remove the `UIWebView` subview before you reuse it as a cell in footer section.