# AVPlayerLayer in Reuse UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, custom-cell, reuseidentifier

I have a logic of playing videos in the cells.

Each time you do play in a cell and move the scroll quickly, the player reappears again. (because `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`).

It occurred to me save the section and row of the cell and ask why whenever `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is activated to show the layer. -> `layer.hidden = NO;`

Also in a poor attempt without positive results, the hidden layer disappears when the cell by doing the following:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndDisplayingCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (indexPath.row == playInRow && indexPath.section == playInSection) {
        layer.hidden = YES;
    }
}
```

I even try to support me in this other function:

```
- (BOOL)isPlayingRowVisible {
    NSArray *indexes = [tableClips indexPathsForVisibleRows];
    for (NSIndexPath *index in indexes) {
        if (index.row == playInRow && index.section == playInSection) {
            return YES;
        }
    }

    return NO;
}
```

Although all attempts, it is not stable (sometimes works, sometimes not) and the problem still occurs to show the layer in a cell that does not belong.

Anyone know a way to solve and / or control this?

Thanks for your time.

**EDITED**

`cellForRowAtIndexPath` code.

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
            SWTableViewCell * cellV;

            ClipVo * clip = [myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

            if ([clip.type isEqualToString:@"video"]) {
                cellV = (SWTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cellVideoChat"];

                if (cellV == nil) {
                    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ChatVideoTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
                    cellV = cellVideoChat;

                    UIView *view = [cellV viewWithTag:14];
                    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(onClickBtnChatVideo:)];
                    tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
                    [view addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
                }
            }
            if (clip.isPlaying && playerClip.rate != 0.0f && [self isPlayingRowVisible] && indexPath.row == playInRow && indexPath.section == playInSection) {
                layer.hidden = NO;
            }

        return cellV;
}
```

**EDITED 2**

Add layer to cell

When the user presses a button that is inside the cell

```
playerClip = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithURL:url];
layer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:playerClip];
layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
UIView *viewContainer = [cell viewWithTag:14];

layer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, viewContainer.frame.size.width, viewContainer.frame.size.height);
[layer setVideoGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect];
[viewContainer.layer insertSublayer:layer below:btnPlayVideo.layer];

[playerClip play];
playInRow = indexpath.row;
playInSection = indexpath.section;
```

Comment: This is because UITableView caches tabiewView cells. Can you please show your cellForRowAtIndexPath code?

Comment: You don't initialise the cell. After you have obtained the "cellV", you need to tell it what to do. Probably http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4620095/uitableview-and-cell-reuse?rq=1 will give you an answer how to do that.

Comment: @jose920405 "layer" is a global variable? How do you define it?

Comment: @shpasta layer is a global variable. I just need a layer for all cells. When this finishes playing is destroyed with `removeFromSuperview`

Comment: So you have one layer for multiple cells? How do you add layer on cells?

Comment: @shpasta code for add layer on cells added.